# How can I style the whole logo including text and image to become a link to the homepage?

Tags: html, css

I want to style the whole logo including text and image to become a link to the homepage. The only condition is that the logo should continue to look and appear the same as it looks and appears now, and the current appearance should continue to be the appearance during hover, and after clicking, and during clicking also. The logo can be seen at top left corner on all pages.

This is my html:

```
<div class="logo">
      <img class="logomap" src="india.jpg" alt="logo" height="47" width="47">mehnat<br>.IN
 </div>
```

Please suggest!!

Comment: Please include the **relevant** code (HTML/JS/CSS) in your question

Comment: Linking somewhere is HTML’s responsibility, not CSS’. Basically all you need to do is add a link around the image and text ... (and then maybe overwrite some default link formatting styles that you don’t like in that place.)

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your whole logo html content with `a` tag like as follows:

```
<a href="your homepage link"> Here comes your all logo html content </a>
```

So as per your logo, the code becomes:

```
<a href="yourlink"> 
   <div class="logo">
      <img class="logomap" src="india.jpg" alt="logo" height="47" width="47">mehnat<br>.IN
  </div>
</a>
```

I have tested at your website, it works well. But the better is to wrap your image within a tag and keep your `div` outside like:

```
<div class="logo">
   <a href="yourlink"> 
      <img class="logomap" src="india.jpg" alt="logo" height="47" width="47">mehnat<br>.IN
   </a>
</div>
```

Please use one of the above two appraaches whatever suits you!

Comment: I usually won't wrap a whole div (Or any other blocked element) with an `a` element, because blocked elements will make the the whole width of the div clickable (Unless it has `display:inline-block/inline` or `float` for example)

Answer (score 0):

wrap the whole content with `a` tag

```
<div class="logo"><a href="link to your homepage"><img class="logomap" src="india.jpg" alt="logo" height="47" width="47">mehnat<br>.IN</a></div>
```